# For an embedding $f:B\to X$, the map $H_n(X,X-f(B)) \to H_n(X,X-x)$ is an isomorphism

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be an $n$-manifold, $B$ an open ball in $\Bbb R^n$, and $f \colon B \to X$ an embedding. For a point $x \in f(B)$, is the map on homology
$$H_n(X,X-f(B)) \to H_n(X,X-x)$$ 
induced by $1 _X$, the identity map of $X$, always an isomorphism?

This is true if $X-x$ deformation retracts onto $X-f(B)$, but I'm not sure about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is wrong. Let $X = \mathbb R^n$ and $f : B  \to X$ be an embedding such that $f(B)$ is an open halfspace. Then $X \setminus f(B)$ is contractible (so that $H_k(X,X \setminus f(B)) = 0$) and $X \setminus \{x\} \simeq S^{n-1}$ (so that $H_k(X,X \setminus \{x\}) = H_k(\mathbb R^n,S^{n-1}$)).

However, it is true if you replace $B$ by a closed $n$-ball $D$. But that is not trivial.

Comment: Good point, I wasn't thinking about things being unbounded